# C# loop until valid answer is given

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm trying to make a text adventure type game, and I am very new to C#. I've searched the web for about half an hour and found nothing that has worked. I want to make something that will not continue until a valid answer is input

This is an example:

```
var answer3 = Console.ReadLine();

if (answer3.Equals("1"))
{
   Console.WriteLine("ans 1");
}
else if (answer3.Equals("2"))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Ans 2");
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("Answer decision 1,2, or 3"); //This is what I need repeated
```

Comment: I don't understand, what you do you want to really achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it that is very C#/.Net is to use Lambda expressions.
You define the list of valid values in an array and it will loop until you get one of these values.

```
string myString = "";
string[] validValues = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" };
while (!validValues.Any(myString.Equals))
    myString = Console.ReadLine();
```

It is equivalent to:

```
string myString = "";
string[] validValues = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" };
while (!validValues.Any(s=>myString.Equals(s))
    myString = Console.ReadLine();

switch (myString)
{
    case "1":
        Console.WriteLine("ans 1");
        break;
    case "2":
        Console.WriteLine("ans 2");
        break;
    case "3":
        Console.WriteLine("ans 3");
        break;
 }
```

`validValues.Any` will return true if the condition in brackets pass on any element. The Lambda expression `s=>myString.Equals(s)` is almost like a function that will return true when the argument `s` is equal to myString. `s` will be replaced by each element of the list when using `Any`.

In this case it is important to notice that `=>` does not mean greater or equal. It means that you defined a function/expression that takes `s` as parameter and returns `myString.Equals(s)`. Then you pass it to `Any`, which will apply it on every element until one returns `true`. If none returned true, `Any` will return `false`.

Lambda expressions are a very neat feature of C#, when you will get used to it, it will allow you to write code which is much simpler than in languages like C++. Since most of us spend alot of time writing boilerplate code or manipulating data obtained from various sources it can make our life alot easier.

More on [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx)

Comment: I feel this is way advanced for me. I like to know what's going on when I type code

Comment: `myString.Contains` what does this do?

Comment: Basically, he has a list of desired answer and checks to see of the user input is within this list. If it is not, ask for more input.

Answer (score 1):

```
do{

    var answer3 = Console.ReadLine();


}while(answer3 != "something" || answer3 != "something else");
```

|| means 'or'

do- while basically executes something at least once, until some condition is true, the while.

```
do{

 this

}while(this isn't true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop

```
string answer = Console.ReadLine();
while(!String.Equals(answer, desiredAnswer)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Answer decision 1,2, or 3");
  answer = Console.ReadLine();  
}
```

If you have multiple desired answers, you can just `OR` them in the `while` condition